# How to cat PostgreSQL's Help Menu

Tags: postgresql, psql

In PostgeSQL's psql interactive terminal, you can type `\?`+`<enter>` to produce a overview that shows a list of common commands. In Ubuntu Linux, is there a way that I can pipe that content to a file that I can `cat` or open up in a GUI text editor?

Comment: Everything from the overview (it's not a "menu") is also available in the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo '\?' | psql > psql_backslash_help.txt
$ head psql_backslash_help.txt 
General
  \copyright             show PostgreSQL usage and distribution terms
  \crosstabview [COLUMNS] execute query and display results in crosstab
  \errverbose            show most recent error message at maximum verbosity
  \g [(OPTIONS)] [FILE]  execute query (and send results to file or |pipe);
                         \g with no arguments is equivalent to a semicolon
  \gdesc                 describe result of query, without executing it
  \gexec                 execute query, then execute each value in its result
  \gset [PREFIX]         execute query and store results in psql variables
  \gx [(OPTIONS)] [FILE] as \g, but forces expanded output mode
```